# Wildfly deploy - LoggerConfigurator is already registered

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly

I have problem with deploying my war application with `Wildfly 10.1.0 Final`.
My problem is:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service 
jboss.pojo."org.jboss.netty.internal.LoggerConfigurator".DESCRIBED 
is already registered
```

I understand - why it happens and know how to solve, but i don't know what is the best solution.

I deploy two wars which have dependency `org.apache.curator:curator-framework:2.9.0` and it transitively has `io.netty:netty:3.7.0.Final`. And as i can see all netty libs from version 3.9.0 and early have `jboss-beans.xml`- and this is the my problem. It should be noted that first war deploy was always successful - exception is thrown when i deploy second war.

What i found for solve this problem:

1. I can add netty with version 3.9.0.Final or higher in my project and it solve my problem - cause gradle will use upper version. But i don't use netty in my project - and don't want to have stub-dependency. **But it works.**
2. I can remove pojo subsystem in wildfly as was done here: [Remove pojo subsystem from wildfly](https://mirocupak.com/duplicate-services-and-the-pojo-subsystem-in-wildfly/) - and it works on my test server, but if i don't have any permissions - i can't do it. And on production srever - i don't have any permissions to 'hack' wildfly. And this solution **works too**.
3. And i can deploy jar with new netty library in Wildfly and after that i can add dependency in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, before it in my wars i should exclude old netty library. **I don't check this way.**
4. I can exclude `pojo` subsystem in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, but i don't actaully know how - i tried smth like:

And it ends with error that `The service container has been destabllilized by previous operation and further runtime updates cann't be processed.`

Answer (score 0):

I think, that in case when you can't remove pojo subsystem - the best way is first solution - cause in all cases we will have netty in our war-file.

Hope, that my deployment pain will helps someone